# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The key path element name is longer than 500 characters exception in App Engine datastore while executing IN query

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

i want to execute `IN` query on app engine Datastore for that i am passing string value to my `ApiMethod` but when i pass lengthy data to my app engine backend then it throws exception as shown below. i don't know whats the problem with my code. Please guide me to solve this issue.

Code :

```
mgr = getEntityManager();
Query query = mgr.createQuery("select f from UserFeedMaster f where f.isFeedDeleted=:delStatus and f.feedBlobKey in (:feedBlob)");
query.setParameter("feedBlob", feedBlob);
query.setParameter("delStatus", false);
```

Exception :

```
    com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: Illegal argument
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Illegal argument
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.NucleusJPAHelper.getJPAExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJPAHelper.java:298)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAAdapter.getApiExceptionForNucleusException(JPAAdapter.java:898)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.QueryExceptionWrappers$2.get(QueryExceptionWrappers.java:72)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterator.hasNext(RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterator.java:103)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.LazyResult.listIterator(LazyResult.java:107)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.StreamingQueryResult.iterator(StreamingQueryResult.java:141)
    at com.sampleregistrationapp.UserFeedMasterEndpoint.getUserFavouriteFeed(UserFeedMasterEndpoint.java:377)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:45)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService.invokeServiceMethod(SystemService.java:359)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.execute(SystemServiceServlet.java:124)
    at com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet.doPost(SystemServiceServlet.java:82)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The key path element name is longer than 500 characters.
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper.translateError(DatastoreApiHelper.java:39)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreApiHelper$1.convertException(DatastoreApiHelper.java:76)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:94)
    at com.google.appengine.api.utils.FutureWrapper.get(FutureWrapper.java:86)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.getInternal(FutureHelper.java:71)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FutureHelper.quietGet(FutureHelper.java:32)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultsSourceImpl.peekQueryResultAndIfFirstRecordIndexList(QueryResultsSourceImpl.java:162)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultsSourceImpl.loadMoreEntities(QueryResultsSourceImpl.java:104)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultsSourceImpl.loadMoreEntities(QueryResultsSourceImpl.java:91)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIteratorImpl.ensureLoaded(QueryResultIteratorImpl.java:142)
    at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultIteratorImpl.hasNext(QueryResultIteratorImpl.java:62)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterator$1.get(RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterator.java:54)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterator$1.get(RuntimeExceptionWrappingIterator.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.QueryExceptionWrappers$1.get(QueryExceptionWrappers.java:49)
    at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.QueryExceptionWrappers$2.get(QueryExceptionWrappers.java:68)
```

Comment: Might be related to this: [LINK](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine-java/UFBFktmPvP0)

Comment: @CeilingGecko actually your link is regarding storing data in datastore while i am facing this issue when i try to fetch data from datastore using `IN` clause. might be possible that data which i am passing to `IN` clause are lengthy . i can't figure out what's the problem. please suggest some solution.

Answer (score 2):

String properties (or key names) in the Datastore cannot exceed 500 characters. This means that there is no point to include a longer string in the list of arguments that you pass to the IN query: you know in advance that this string will not have any matches.

UPDATE

If you store BlobKey in your entity property, make sure that you pass a BlobKey as a parameter, and not the String representation of that key. If necessary, convert strings into BlobKey:

```
BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(blobKeyString);
```

Comment: here i am passing list of Blobkeys which are generated by app engine itself, so do i require to check length of blobkeys? Is there any chances that blobkey will have value longer than 500 characters?

Comment: How do you get these keys? Something is wrong about them. Do you convert them into strings and back?

Comment: actually i am uploading blob on app engine and using blobkey to fetch record. Here, i am passing below values `AMIfv95PX89oBVYfrOb-Ssnq3kpwI3lE95zONxd_gEEDiJxNLvFASjVi-C87FvUH6YWAVlxXIdywmm5C7fzbJtYMuQ6XjGLSQcYmxD_zEBL91ofuVtUzV4NO8SMfeQqLT7ZkT1GE_O8nV406lcsjFx1AQ7YYkGwPrbl37xS6VGLYcUJvQ9_u8bQ,AMIfv96jecQ_uprOv9buLTgBEc3WO9r4vZPbWV4coSYvb6mtZCvY8P-puOzUmaW17zhZSOi1BDT9rquFcqm0vmHhIKM04_cDfvE30oP_RXvyGQ0PwR8N6NrwEtrLs6IDnpvN9Gm1kdKBGdE_k-SpZ7QVAn32kyQGVNGQJC5ZqYOaL_IiPKa2HDQ` which already exist on datastore but it returns null response.

Comment: ok..so you are trying to say that i'll have to store `blobkey` values as `BlobKey` type in Datastore but will it allow to pass multiple blobkey values to `IN` query?

Comment: Yes, Blobkey property can be indexed. By the way, the String in your example is 375 characters, so it cannot cause 500-character limit problem.

Comment: yes,but here i am passing only 2 blobKey values therefore its not causing any problem but if i pass more than 2 values then it causes problem.

Comment: actually i am using this endpoint class in my android client and from android client i am passing blobKey values to backend app engine. Therefore i am using `query.setParameter("feedBlob", feedBlob)`.

Comment: It sounds the query may be interpreting your two keys as a single string. I'm not super familiar with JPA, but is it possible that your feedBlob type is of type String and that JPA is escaping it so that the query is looking up a single key with a comma in the name? From the datastore's perspective, you can do an IN query with multiple values as long as each individual values are valid (the key lengths won't add together).